# SFML how do I create walkable ground?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

For as far as I have gone, I have managed to make it seem like a texture is moving in the ground, but what actually was happening is that I set the position of the `Ground` sprite a little below the `Character` sprite, and I as moved the `Character` only in the X coordinates I made it seem like it was moving on the ground.
Now, I know that there must be another way, probably with pixel collusion(Give a `true` when 2 objects `pixels` hit)

Anyway that is for as far as I know, I do not know if I should use yet another library for that manner.

Example on the inefficient way I am doing it:

```
sf::texture cTexture,gTexture;
sf::sprite character,ground;
character.setPosition(0,400);
ground.setPosition(0,390);
```

In this way by moving :

```
character.move(1.5,0.f);
```

It seems as if it would be moving in the ground, which I mostly said, is not.

Please inform me on a more efficient way, even better a class friendly one!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. There will always be `sf::Texture` and `sf::Sprite` underlying. Why efficiency? You should first care about some of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design#Design_considerations).

Comment: I didn't mean use another form for displaying images, a form of moving sprites in a simplier way over another texture without limiting the walk over 'X' and 'Y' coordinates

Comment: Still, I don't understand. Is the above not good for you? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you're trying to make platformer, and as far as I understood you're trying to figure out system that moves sprite in a other way than manipulating X,Y coordinates? If so then sadly there's no other way, every game is based on manipulating X,Y,(Z) coordinates and render texture/sprite/whatever at that position. What you're really looking for(if I got answer right) is physics(the collision detection to be precise). SFML already has some collision detection in the sprite class(actually in the FloatRect but sprite class consist of float rect variable)

```
//If a sprite contains given point then it will return true
if(sprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(otherSprite.getPosition()))
{
  some collision handling, returning to previous position before moving or whatever
}
//or
//If a sprite intersects other "bounding box" then true
if(sprite.getGlobalBounds().intersects(otherSprite.getGlobalBounds()))
{
// same as above
}
```

I recommend reading sfml wiki/manual, some tutorials on yt or sfml guide book.
If you dont like handling physics stuff by yourself you can use Box2D library, it's very good physics library but if you're starting with getting basics of gamedev physics just go with "manual" one ;)

Good luck and have fun :)